# should I use impersonation in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, impersonation

Our organization has web applications that are mostly used internally by users who have Active Directory accounts.  Currently, each of our application runs under its own AD account.  We grant access to the application AD accounts on the database side for data access.

Our DBA wants to move away from this for auditing reasons.  He wants each data request that comes from the application to come with the logged in user's AD credentials, rather than the application's AD credentials.  I understand this is something that is accomplished using impersonation.  Is this a recommended practice?  What are the benefits and the downsides? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the following to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The web server will "impersonate the authenticated user" and your DBA will see the user's network id.  You can also use the configuration file to impersonate a specific user:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="user" password="pwd" />
```

but that is not what your DBA is looking for in this case.

Yes, "impersonation" may sound odd, but this is a perfectly standard way of authenticating web application users on your internal network.  You will have to make sure that each of your users has the necessary folder permissions, etc, to do everything they need to do, since the web server is now doing these things in their name, not in the name of a general application user.  You will hear about these permissions issues pretty quickly when users try to do things they used to be able to do, and get access denied instead.  But once they each have been given the necessary permissions it will be okay.

Comment: +1 - I would add that all application users should be placed in an application group, and the group should be granted the necessary permissions (not the individual users).

Comment: yes, that's what the DBA proposes to do is to roll a group policy.

Comment: thanks for the info @criticalfix.  I had never encountered such a thing before, so I was kind of on the fence.